Configure IRSA to access mongodb cluster from EKS pod
I'm trying to setup a IRSA(Iam Role for Service Account) in order to acces mongodb cluster from EKS cluster.
The IRSA will then be attached to my EKS pod.(The goal is to setup passwordless authentication in mongodb atlas, and access mongodbfrom my EKS podusing IAM role)
As per the following documentation, a policy should be created an attached to the role.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html
The policy should define the permissions to the resource that my pod need to access. In my case, it is mongodb.
How can i specify in the policy that ressource to be access is mongodb?
Note: mongodb clusyer is setup in mongodb atlas and we are accessing through a VPC enpoint.
Thanks a lot.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/passwordless-authentication/

Hello Phill. Thanks for your answer.  I'm actually blocked with the role creation. The role need to be created and assigned to the pod. About the IAM policy, Which resource should be specified in the policy that I will create for the role to be attached to my pod? Thanks

The way I'm reading it, you shouldn't need any resource policies. What you will need is a trust policy to allow EKS to perform AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity as per these instructions.

Hi Phill, in the documentation, it is mentioned to create the IAM role using the following command:
eksctl create iamserviceaccount --name my-service-account --namespace default --cluster my-cluster --role-name my-role 
--attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::111122223333:policy/my-policy --approve.
Do you mean it is not needed to include the --attach-policy-arn option?
